# fade in hover that stays solid once clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do something seemingly very simple but having NO luck figuring out how to mesh the code I already have with the tiny detail I want.

I have image links that call divs filled with text. I need the images to fade in to full on hover and STAY full opacity once clicked UNLESS someone clicks a different image.

The script I have for the fading in of the text divs fades them in beautifully, which is why I am keeping this code I have used before... However I am open to meshing it together with the *fade in hover and stay in styling or script* that I need sorted out, or changing the JQuery script entirely so that everything functions together the right way.

This is the code for my image buttons.

```
<bioimage1><a href="javascript:showDiv('biotext1')" class="fade"><img src="update_feb_2014/bio_images/1.jpg" width="115" height="115" border="0"/></a></bioimage1>
```

This is the CSS class I am using to make my images fade in on hover:

```
.fade {
opacity: 0.5;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

Here is the JQuery/Javascript that is controlling the fade in of the text divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var option = 'biotext2';
        var url = window.location.href;
        option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
        showDiv(option);
});
    function showDiv(option) {
        $('.hidden').fadeOut(700);   
        $('#' + option).fadeIn(700);
        $('#biotextmain').fadeOut(700);   
    }

    $(function(){ 
        $('#' + option).fadeIn(700);
        });
```

This is an example of one of the 15 text divs that fade in:

```
<div id="biotext1" class="hidden">1 this is my bio this is my bio This is my bio</div>
```

I think that covers it. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should not `showDiv()` and `$('#' + option).fadeIn(700);` be inside the `document.ready(){..}` function?

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
<bioimage1>
    <a data-target="biotext1" href="#" class="fade">
        <img src="update_feb_2014/bio_images/1.jpg" width="115" height="115" border="0"/>
    </a>
</bioimage1>

<div id="biotext1" class="hidden">
    1 this is my bio this is my bio This is my bio
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $hiddens = $('.hidden');
    var option = 'biotext2';
    var $fades = $('.fade').click(showDiv);

    //var url = window.location.href;
    //option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    $fades.filter('[data-target="' + option + '"]').click();


    function showDiv() {
        var $this = $(this),
            option = $this.data('target');
        $fades.removeClass('clicked')
        $this.addClass('clicked');
        $hiddens.fadeOut(700);
        $('#' + option).fadeIn(700);
        $('#biotextmain').fadeOut(700);
    }

});
```

and

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade:hover, .fade.clicked {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hidden {
    display:none
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3xCtD/)

Comment: YOU my dear sir are brilliant! It works perfectly! It's 2:20AM here and I can finally go to sleep because of this accomplishment. This was driving me CRAZY! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Would you mind explaining how I could get the div to be called on hover instead of click, in case I decide to go that route? I tried replacing "click" with "hover" but it is buggy and wants to fade in and out the last div activated on top of the current div being called, at the same time. If it's a complicated fix, don't worry about it. I just thought perhaps it may be an easy change that I'm missing.

Comment: @Naomi sorry... what do you mean by hover instead of click...you already have an effect for the hover event.... what do you want to do on hover?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove your .fade class on click. Your behavior is on that hook, so it should do what you want. Also, attach your default CSS opacity to that hook, and you'll remove the default opacity so that when you mouse off, the image won't go back to its beginning state. Does that help?